# iOS-Use CocoaPods import framework，but can't use it

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

my Xcode version is 7.3 and Mac Version is 10.11.4

I use `pod setup` and `pod install` get a new .xcworkspace file,and I open this file too.

but I still can't use `#import "  "` or `#import < >` import some header files in Pods(I can see this header files in pod project) Xcode tell me not found this files.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it for myself. You should to your project->build settings->User Header Search Paths and add  `${SRCROOT}` choose recursive.
This is work for me.

Answer (score 8):

Clean the project. Try building your project without the import statement to start. Then try building again with the import statement.